# Record doesn't shows as saved, paragraph problems

Tags: php, mysql

This question may be downgraded but I am simply unable to find a solution even after searching everywhere I could.

My php application uses database to store information about products. Everything works fine. The product table has a column "product description". The product description is saved via "ckeditor". The product description to be saved has paragraphs (two three of them). Till here no problems whatsoever.

When the records are retrieved the paragraphs disappears and is shown in a single line without any paragraphs.

```
For example 
This a paragraph 1
This a paragraph 2
This a paragraph 3
```

Shows up as 
This a paragraph 1 \r\n\r\n This a paragraph 2 \r\n\r\n This a paragraph 3

I tried using nl2br() but this didn't help. Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong.

I am adding the code below as asked

```
    $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO products (productName, productDescription) VALUES(?,?,?)";
    if($stmt = $connect->prepare($sql) )
        {
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $productname, $productdescription);

        if($stmt->execute())
           {
                echo "Product created";
                $stmt->close();

            }else{
                die("Unable to create");
            }
            }else{
                die("Unable to prepare statement.");
            }
                $connect->close();
            }
    }
```

I use mysqli prepared statement for saving it to the mysql db.

To retrieve:

```
 while($row = $results->fetch_array()) 
{
extract($row);
echo "{$productName}";
echo "{$productDescription}";
}
```

Comment: Please post the code belonging to your question - we can't tell what's wrong when we can't see your code (only the parts reading the db entries should be enough)

Comment: Also the raw output form nl2br() would be useful

Comment: @chill0r did add the codes .... please check.

Answer (score 1):

nl2br() is exactly what you need for this problem. Perhaps there is a problem with the way you are using it. Could you include an example of the code that is not working for you?

```
$description = "This a paragraph 1 \r\n\r\n This a paragraph 2 \r\n\r\n This a paragraph 3";

// this should output
// "This a paragraph 1 <br />\r\n<br />\r\n This a paragraph 2 <br />\r\n<br />\r\n This a paragraph 3"
echo nl2br($description);
```

Note that these are not paragraphs, they are line breaks.

in your code to retrieve change this line:

```
echo "{$productDescription}";
```

to this:

```
echo nl2br($productDescription);
```

Comment: Ill do and check again. Thank you for advising.